# How do I make the squiggly line in metapost?

Tags: graphics, metapost

[image]

I can do the normal line, but don't know how I'm supposed to do the squiggly one.

Code is this:

```
beginfig(1); 
  numeric u;
  u=1cm;
  path ytelg;
  ytelg := (0,-0.25u)--(0,3u);
  path xtelg;
  xtelg := (-0.25u,0)--(5u,0);
  drawarrow xtelg;
  drawarrow ytelg;
  path koverjoon;
  koverjoon := (0.6u,1.8u)..(1.5u,1.35u)..(2u,1.2u)..(4u,0.8u);
  draw koverjoon;
  path joon;
  joon := (0.6u,1.6u)..(0.68u,1.71u)..(0.80u,1.815u)..(0.93u,1.74u)..(0.907u,1.6u)..(0.85u,1.5u);
  path joonis;
  joonis := joon shifted(0.25u,-0.1u);
  draw joonis shifted (0.25u,-0.1u);
  draw joonis shifted (0.5u,-0.2u);
  draw joonis shifted (0.75u,-0.3u);
  path koverjoonkaks;
  koverjoonkaks := (1.85u,1.1u)..(1.94u,1.22u)..(2.06u,1.32u)..(2.22u,1.31u)..(2.25u,1.20u)..(2.25u,1.0u);
  draw koverjoonkaks shifted (0.4u,-0.1u);
  draw koverjoonkaks;
  draw koverjoonkaks shifted (0.8u,-0.2u);
  draw koverjoonkaks shifted (1.2u, -0.3u);
  draw joonis;
  draw joon;
endfig;
end
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome. I also wonder what you tried. But also if it should look a bit random as in the picture or more like a spring?

Comment: edited my post, obviously doesn't look very similar. Regarding on what it should look, it should look more like a computer made it I believe, since the the randomness in the original photo is just a result of the author's handwriting.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code for a minimal example showing what you've tried or what you can do, so people don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Please don't vote to immediately close new users' questions before they've had a chance to improve them!

Comment: Now that there is a MWE, in which way should the result look different? Should it be more regular? Or even more squiggly?

Comment: Like @JasperHabicht I'm not sure what's wrong with the current line. It looks pretty squiggly. Is it supposed to be more even or ...?

Comment: @cfr yeah I guess it will do,  I just made this post since I don't know how strict the overseer of my file is,so because basically this image is meant to go into a group project for some materials on splines, which masters students study, so don't know if he would accept it or would want something less chaotic like mickep posted, but thanks for your answers, I think mickep produced an image, which I most desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want, but you probably want to loop. Below is a version that might use some MetaFun specifics, but hopefully you get the idea and can transform it into pure MetaPost if necessary (or use `context`).

```
\startMPpage[offset=1DK]

vardef tangentvector(expr pp,tt) =
  unitvector ((postcontrol tt on pp) - (precontrol tt on pp))
enddef;

vardef rightnormalvector(expr pp,tt) =
  tangentvector(pp,tt) rotated -90
enddef;

vardef leftnormalvector(expr pp,tt) =
  tangentvector(pp,tt) rotated 90
enddef;

vardef totheleft(expr pp,tt,oo) =
  point tt on pp
  shifted ((oo,0) rotated (angle leftnormalvector(pp,tt)))
enddef;

vardef totheright(expr pp,tt,oo) =
  point tt on pp 
  shifted ((oo,0) rotated (angle rightnormalvector(pp,tt)))
enddef;

vardef squigglypath(expr pp,oo,n) =
  save lp, ip ; numeric lp, ip ;
  lp := arclength(pp) ;
  for i = 0 upto (2*n) :
    hide (ip := (i/(2*n))*lp ;)
    if odd i :
      totheleft(pp,ip,oo) {tangentvector(pp,ip)} ..
    else :
      if i <> 0 :
        {rightnormalvector(pp,ip)}
      fi
      totheright(pp,ip,oo) {leftnormalvector(pp,ip)} .. 
    fi
  endfor
  nocycle
enddef;

numeric u ; u := 1cm ;
path p ; p := (.5u,3u){dir -75} .. (4u,2u) .. {dir 40}(8u,u) ;

draw p ;
draw squigglypath(subpath(0.25,1.75) of p, .15u , 15) withcolor darkred ;
drawdblarrow (0,3.5u) -- origin -- (8.5u,0) ;
\stopMPpage
```

Running `context` on the file above I get:

[image: squiggly path]

Answer (score 2):

There is doubtless a superior way to do this since my knowledge of MetaPost is extremely limited.

### *Caveat emptor*

You could use `nccoil` or `nczigzag` from the `metaobj` package. If you are used to basic MetaPost, the syntax is a bit awkward at first. (At least, *I* kept getting compilation errors due to stupid typos. *You* will likely have no such difficulty.)

The following may be more coil-like than you want, but you can adjust the `coilwidth` and `coilheight` to change the tightness and spacing of the coils. `coilarmA` and `coilarmB` determine the length along the curve before the coils start. These parts are not actually curved, so I kept them short here, but it seemed a bit easier to control things if they aren't `0pt`.

If you can approximate the original path as a Bezier --- as opposed to multiple connected segments --- you could get a more perfect fit, because both `nccoil` and `nczigzag` apply to Beziers rather than segments.

```
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701970/ i gwestiwn hellusENG: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701924/
input metaobj

beginfig(3);
  numeric u;
  u=1cm;
  path ytelg;
  ytelg := (0,-0.25u)--(0,3u);
  path xtelg;
  xtelg := (-0.25u,0)--(5u,0);
  drawarrow xtelg;
  drawarrow ytelg;
  path koverjoon;
  z0=(0.6u,1.8u);
  z1=(1.5u,1.35u);
  z2=(2u,1.2u);
  z3=(4u,0.8u);
  koverjoon := z0..z1..z2..z3;
  draw koverjoon;
  nccoil(z0)(z3)"angleA(-40)","angleB(-10)",
  "coilwidth(u/10)","coilheight(1pt)","linetension(1.3)","linecolor(black)","arrows(-)","coilarmA(2.5pt)","coilarmB(2.5pt)";
endfig;
bye;
```

[image: coil along curve]